# Simultaneous electronic shutter release for multiple Lumix G7 cameras

Tags: resistance, camera, synchronous, trigger

I'm trying to trigger six Panasonic Lumix G7 cameras at once.

The trigger mechanism uses a four pole 2.5 mm plug, some resistors and two switches. With no switch closed there is 41 kilohms of resistance. To trigger the focus, you reduce that to 5 kilohms. To trigger the photograph or video start you allow 2 kilohms of resistance.

So much I learnt from this great blog post: http://www.robotroom.com/Macro-Photography-2.html

[image: Resistor diagram]

Wired this way it triggers a single camera just fine. However, when you add additional cameras to the circuit, it doesn't work anymore. I'm guessing that the resistance is no longer correct, because now the focus trigger does nothing (I think) and a shutter release trigger makes one camera focus.

When I was 11 I was the proud owner of a DSE Funway into Electronics set. I'm afraid I've learnt nothing much since then.

Any way to wire this up so that the resistance is correct for all the cameras? Ideally I could add more than 6 cameras in the future following the same method.

My fall back are independent circuits with a mechanical switch closing them all independently, but 1/100 second accuracy would be a big help here, so I'd love to do it right.

Cheers,

Red

Comment: Have you considered fast solid state relays or optoisolators?

Comment: are you using a single set of resistors for all cameras? I think you might need to use a set of resistors for each camera, and then use some active circuitry to drive them all at the same time as alex said.

Comment: The camera is likely to have a resistor internally to form a voltage divider, does what is marked as 3.1 V change as the buttons are pressed? If so it might be worth measuring and updating your post that'd open up a few other options.

Comment: I suspect @PeterJ is spot on here -- knowing what voltages need to be present when the buttons are present helps tremendously here.  Also, what's on the other two connector terminals?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I really don't know what the other terminals are used for. Panansonic's wired shutter release (DMW-RS1) doesn't expose any additional functionality than I've already achieved with just the sleeve and the single ring.

@PeterJ That's a good question. I just picked up a cheap multi-meter, so I'll try to find out.

Comment: Can you guys also take a look at the Answer below and render an opinion on it? I'm nervous about introducing a power source, because up to now I felt that at least I wouldn't bungle my way into frying one or more cameras! I would have to follow it by rote because I don't understand the circuit.

Comment: I don't see any problems with it the voltage is isolated. But try this test - replace the 2K on the shutter button in your current setup with a 330 ohm resistor and see if it works with all six cameras. If it does I can post an answer explaining how it's all working.

Comment: I don't know if I'm following the procedure correctly, but plugging in a lead to a single camera and then measuring the voltage across the sleeve and the first ring, I get 1.78 volts. It doesn't vary with a focus press or a shutter release.

For the 2K substitution (can it be as easy as divide by 6?) I'll need to buy a 330 Ohm resistor to try that.

@ThreePhaseEel

Comment: Are you pressing the buttons on the camera, or on the cable? (You may need a TRRS Y-cable or Y-adapter to measure this)

Answer (score 1):

ordinary mechanical relays are fast enough to manage 1/1000 second accuracy

have one set of relay cntacts and one set of resistors for each camera. (or two contacts if you needs focus and shutter)

solid-state relays can be non-ideal in interesting ways, but the right one could work too,

or you could do it in discrete transistors like this;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHeJ7k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(immagine that repeating bit four more times)

Comment: Thanks very much! Anyway that I fry one or more cameras if I bungle this? I'm nervous about introducing a power source to the circuit.

Comment: Also, and I really don't know what I'm doing here, when I tried it on CircuitLab in DC test mode it showed 9V at the sleeve and ring. Is that right?